# How can I do an window key event with Angularjs to set an angular variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keydown

I don't know how I can intercept a keydown event of the window and set from there an angular var into the scope, of a specify controller.

Comment: Use ngKeydown directive on body for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it from your controller.

```
angular.element(window).bind("keydown",keydown);
function keydown(e) {
    $scope.eventKeydown = e.keyCode;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
window.onkeydown = keydown;

function keydown(e) {
    $scope.eventKeydown = e;
    console.log(e);
    console.log($scope.eventKeydown);
}
```